# How to select the immediate characters BEFORE a specific string in SQL

Tags: sql

So imagine I have a SQL tempTable with a text field with 2 pages worth of text in it.

```
select * from tempTable
```

| pkid | text |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | This is an example text with some images names like image1.svg or another one like image2.svg |
| 1 | This is another example text image3.svg and several images more like image4 and image5 |

What I want to know is if it's possible to select the characters before the .svg extension, so that the select result would look like

| result |
| --- |
| ike image1.svg |
| ike image2.svg |
| ext image3.svg |

and so on.
I've alread read about CHARINDEX and SUBSTRING, but I've only been able to find selects that return ALL text before my filter (.svg).

Comment: Do you always want to select the 10 chars before the .svg? Also, you say you want to select the chars before .svg but in your example results you are also including the .svg chars - can you confirm what you actually want?

Comment: @NickW 10 chars is just an example, if it's possible I'd like to be able to put any number. If that's not possible, 30 would be great.  I prefer that the results include the .svg chars, but I can do without it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found a way to do it. This is the query I used using `PATINDEX()`.

```
select pkid, SUBSTRING (text, PATINDEX('%.svg%',text)-60,65) 
from tempTable 
where text like '%.svg%'
```

This way you can either return ALL text before desired word/expression, or get a certain number of characters before, you just need to change the substring ranges.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I came up with. This uses the [string_split](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) and [LAG](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) functions in MSSQL, but other database engines have similar features.

```sql
--create the temp table
DECLARE @temp AS TABLE (
 pkid int,
 text nvarchar(max)
)

--populate the temp table
INSERT INTO @temp (pkid, text) VALUES
(0, 'This is an example text with some images names like image1.svg or another one like image2.svg'),
(1, 'This is another example text image3.svg and several images more like image4 and image5')

--run the query to get the desired results
SELECT
    CONCAT(RIGHT(split.priorValue, 10), '.svg') AS result
FROM (
SELECT
    ss.value,
    LAG(ss.value, 1) OVER (ORDER BY pkid) AS priorValue
FROM @temp
CROSS APPLY string_split(text, '.') ss
) AS split
WHERE split.value LIKE 'svg%'
```